# Print object information as toString() without toString()?

Tags: java, logging, tostring, simulate

my Question is, is it possible to print out specific information from a class that provides no toString() method in JAVA?

There's the rub: We provide a logger for our application (using aspectJ) which prints out the specific arguments, that were given. For example:

```
public void addGroupMembers(Group group, String doneBy, DataListModel<User> users) {
    doSomething()
}
```

And our Logger prints the following:

```
addGroupMembers called with given arguments:
Group = [id = ..... and so on]
username
DataListModel$1231 <-
```

We have to use the DataListModel-Class, because we're working with JSF in the background. But, as you can see, this class doesn't provide a toString method.

Our logger is written by ourself, so we can adapt that. Is it possible to simulate a toString method like: If the class doesn't provide a toString, catch all their fields, and print them?

Or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Greetings, Thunderhook

Comment: It's not obvious who "owns" the DataListModel class... but it sounds like something you'd want to configure on the aspect, if you can't add the `toString` method yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of [ReflectionToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html).  Something like:

```
if (object.toString().endsWith("@" + Integer.toHexString(object.hashCode())) {
  // default toString()...
  return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(object);
}
else {
  return object.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this existed.

Comment: This sounds promising, i will give it a try on monday! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I've done this a few times using reflection.  I had a generic method that was essentially `dumpObject` that iterated through the fields and put them to a string.  This works great, but be sure to consider performance if you're calling this often - it might be better to hard code the tostring. e.g.,

```
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true); 
        log.info(field.getName()
                 + " - " + field.getType()
                 + " - " + field.get(obj));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, something like this was already on my mind, I will also give it a try on monday!